# Turf.js midpoint of line

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, turf

I'd like to open a popup in on the midpoint of a polyline/linestring in Mapbox GL, like it's the default case in Leaflet.

How can I do this via turf.js? If I use centroid/center/centerOfMass it will get a point usually not on the line, but somewhere next to it.

My only idea is to:

1. Measure the lenght of the line in some units
2. Use `along()` with the half of the measured distance.

Is this really the best option?

Comment: That sounds like the best option to me.

Comment: I've tried the midpoint() function from Turf, but the point was not along the line.
Then I came across this answer, and tried the approach of first calculating the line length and then moving half the length on the line.
It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue, see my screen[image]

I fixed it by use the post author's idea, successfully place the center point along the line.
This is my code to fix the issue.
[image]

This is fixed result, compare it with top screen (unfixed issue)

[image]