# Turf.js length gives incorrect result

Tags: turf

I'm trying to calculate the distance between 2 points given by GPS coordinates using the turf.js library. My code looks like this:

```
const s1 = {
    lat: 48.60538779779193,
    lng: 18.887075288025212
}

const s2 = {
    lat: 48.60544807307272,
    lng: 18.887834925208427
}

const lineString = turf.lineString([[s1.lat, s1.lng], [s2.lat, s2.lng]]);
const lLength = turf.length(lineString, {units: "meters"});
console.log(lLength);
```

This yields an incorrect result of 84.705625m

I tried calculate it using this site - https://www.fcc.gov/media/radio/distance-and-azimuths

This one gives a correct result:
[image]

Also measuring the 2 points in QGIS shows a distance of 56.4m

What's the catch here? Is turf.js buggy or am I missing something?

Comment: Cross posted to https://stackoverflow.com/: [Turf.js length gives incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68784809/turf-js-length-gives-incorrect-result)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake is in wrong order of coordinates. turf.js requires `[lng, lat]` order (see for example http://turfjs.org/docs/#point).

So if you calculate like this

```
const lineString = turf.lineString([[s1.lng, s1.lat], [s2.lng, s2.lat]]);
const lLength = turf.length(lineString, {units: "meters"});
```

, you'll get:

```
56.254338683733785
```

Answer (score 0):

I have working sample code in this question answer,

please click here

[Turf.js midpoint of line](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/281974/turf-js-midpoint-of-line/449896#449896)