# Are lines drawn on most web maps wrong?

Tags: google-earth-engine, leaflet, mapbox

Lets imagine a shortest path (on the surface of earth ellipsoid) between CA, US and Greenland. Also lets add a point on the middle of that path. If we now draw the path as a line on a map using different map engines, the results are not the same. Here are the results of that drawn path and a middle point on Google Earth Engine, Mapbox and Leaflet. Since with only GEE the line intersects the middle point I would assume that the lines drawn with Mapbox and Leaflet are not correct?

GEE (https://code.earthengine.google.com/e8e6c2db2b3a79b0435a66e80744e7ea):

[image]

Mapbox (https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/sweet-water-35gqp9):

[image]

[image]

Leaflet (https://codepen.io/ristiisa/pen/mdoQLZO):

[image]

Comment: It depends on whether you want a geodetic line or a rhumb line. Do read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhumb_line and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_on_an_ellipsoid

Comment: @IvanSanchez regardless how the line looks, the point should be on the line

Comment: All map are "wrong" as all projections of a sphere on a plane necessarily distort the surface in some way and to some extent (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection) What you show are just different kind of wrong (and different interpretation of what a line on a sphere mean…)

Comment: @J.R projection is not wrong, but in this case it is irrelevant as only one example intersects with the point out of the examples given

Comment: @ristiisa Please read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection#Metric_properties_of_maps

Comment: @ristiisa so it depend on what you mean by "draw a line between CA, US and Greenland " if it's join start and end point by a straight line (a rhumb line in some projection) then the last two picture are right, if it's drawing a line that would be the shortest on the surface of a globe (geodesics) the first picture is right. The straight line way may seem "wrong" but on a Mercator projection it give a constant bearing and allow use of a compass to navigate (see the Marine navigation of this wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection).

Comment: The thing is your middle point is NOT part of the line ,so depending on the projection and on what type of line you draw it could be on the line or not (the three points stay at the same position in all your exemple the only difference is witch line you draw to join  the point)

Comment: @J.R I am talking about a shortest path between two points. There is only one shortest path. That path will. have a start, end and a middle. Depending on projection that path will look different. But it will still have a start, end and a middle. All those 3 points will intersect with the drawn line. If you look at how leflet and mapbox have drawn the line then the middle point does not intersect with the drawn line.

Comment: @ristiisa Then you might want to rephrase your question. Instead of "are most web maps wrong?" do something like "Why do most web maps use straight lines in mercator that do not represent the shortest path (geodetic line) between two points?"

Comment: How have you calculated the midpoint in each application? In your leaflet code you have hardcoded the midpoint with X and Y coords which im assuming you derived from GEE, so yes the midpoint will be different across the applications if you simply hard-code it. If you change your code to calculate midpoint on the fly in each app, it should be in each and on the line.

Comment: @nr_aus the shortest path will have only one midpoint. The GEE and mapbox examples both show the calculation of the midpoint. In the leaflet example the coordinates are lat and lng not cartesian x and y.

Comment: @ristiisa - I think it might have something to do with your code, im going to post an answer, because it requires some formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Just some info to help debug.

What I did to verify was use your Mapbox link.

In your Mapbox code, you declare centerPoint, but you dont use it. However it does have values hardcoded, which im going to assume is the 'incorrectly' placed midpoint.

```
const centerPoint = [-73.975547, 40.691785];
```

Then you declare the linestring.

```
const line = turf.lineString([[-115.19056694158435, 36.1943265363222], [-49.674793172420024, 62.02064170269384]]);
```

Then you declare your midpoint.

```
const midpoint = turf.circle(turf.midpoint(line.geometry.coordinates[0], line.geometry.coordinates[1]).geometry.coordinates, 10, options);
```

What I did for reference, is I took the values from your lineString, and plugged them into a desktop GIS system and created a line geometry based on WGS84, which is generally the coordinate system used for webGIS systems. Then I calculated a new geometry, which is the midpoint of that line. The following are the x,y values, which are on the line, as you can see in my picture.

```
-82.433
49.107
```

[image]

I know you don't use centrePoint variable, however the values in that are different to the above. So something is different!

Reading the turf midpoint documentation, I found the following:

> "The Turf. js midpoint measurement takes two points and returns a
> point midway between them. The midpoint is calculated geodesically,
> meaning the curvature of the earth is taken into account. "

In other words, its calculating the midpoint between two points, not the midpoint of the line geometry. This would also explain why my desktop GIS midpoint calculation is on the line.

If you need to show the midpoint of the line, have a look at this thread, where someone else seems to have had the same problem.

[Turf.js midpoint of line](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/281974/turf-js-midpoint-of-line)